# AVCaptureSession goes to crash

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using that code to take photos I'm able to take photos not quickly as possible.
Shooting multiple photos quickly the app goes to crash.

I'm using Swift 1.1.

Error:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',        reason: ' +[AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:] 
- NULL sample buffer.'**

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?
    var captureConnection: AVCaptureConnection?
    var stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
    let targetRegion = CALayer()
    var currentImage: UIImage?

    @IBOutlet weak var cameraView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageDisplayed: UIImageView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)

        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080
        let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()
        for device in devices {
            if device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
                if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back {
                    captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice
                }
            }
        }
        if captureDevice != nil {
            println("Device trovato")
            beginSession()
        }


    }


    func beginSession() {

        var err: NSError? = nil
        captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice, error: &err))

        if err != nil {
            println("err \(err?.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

        previewLayer?.frame = CGRect(x: cameraView.frame.origin.x, y: cameraView.frame.origin.y, width: cameraView.frame.size.width, height: cameraView.frame.size.height)

        captureSetup()
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }

    func captureSetup() {

        let outputSetting = NSDictionary(dictionary: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG])
        self.stillImageOutput.outputSettings = outputSetting
        self.captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
        for connection:AVCaptureConnection in self.stillImageOutput.connections as [AVCaptureConnection] {

            for port:AVCaptureInputPort in connection.inputPorts! as [AVCaptureInputPort] {
                if port.mediaType == AVMediaTypeVideo {
                    captureConnection = connection as AVCaptureConnection
                    break
                }
            }
            if captureConnection != nil {
                break
            }
        }
    }


    var i = 0;

    func captureScene() {


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
            if self.captureConnection != nil {
                self.stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(self.captureConnection, completionHandler:{ (imageSampleBuffer:CMSampleBuffer!, _) -> Void in

                    let imageDataJpeg = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageSampleBuffer)
                    var pickedImage: UIImage = UIImage(data:imageDataJpeg)!



                    if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage) {


                        let filename = self.getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(self.i).png")
                        data.writeToFile(filename, atomically: true)

                        self.i++
                    }


                })
            }
        })

    }



    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> NSString {
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let documentsDirectory: AnyObject = paths[0]


        return documentsDirectory as NSString
    }




    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        captureScene()
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use avfoundation to capture image, but can not capture too quickly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024282/use-avfoundation-to-capture-image-but-can-not-capture-too-quickly)

Comment: Can you explain the answer about the either same question? Thank you

Comment: Very simple: check that `imageSampleBuffer` is not nil, because sometimes it is if you take several pics quickly. // I see that your signature for `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` has a *non-optional* `imageSampleBuffer`. I believe it's a Swift 1 problem, in Swift 2 it's an Optional and you can check it for nil. With Swift 1, you should seek if there's an error parameter available for this function and use it.

Comment: Please re write as an answer so I can vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @alper explains in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11180358/2227743) is that sometimes `imageSampleBuffer` can be nil, and this is the source of the crash.

---

I believe that in Swift 2 `imageSampleBuffer` is an Optional, so to avoid this crash you can check for nil. Example:

```
if imageSampleBuffer != nil {
    let imageDataJpeg = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageSampleBuffer)
    // ...
} else {
    // handle or ignore the error
}
```

But you're using Swift 1 and it's a problem because in Swift 1 `imageSampleBuffer` is declared as an implicitly unwrapped optional, meaning that it can't be nil and you can't check like in the previous example.

The solution given by @alper is to use

```
CMSampleBufferIsValid(imageSampleBuffer)
```

as a way to check if the buffer is valid or not.

---

*If the previous solution doesn't work, you can try this.*

When I look at the function signature:

```
self.stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(self.captureConnection, completionHandler:{ (imageSampleBuffer:CMSampleBuffer!, _) -> Void in
```

I see that there's another parameter next to the buffer but you're ignoring it:

> (imageSampleBuffer:CMSampleBuffer!, _)

I didn't look for the Swift 1 documentation but I wouldn't be surprised if the `_` was actually an error parameter. Try replacing it with `error` like this:

```
self.stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(self.captureConnection, completionHandler:{ (imageSampleBuffer:CMSampleBuffer!, error) -> Void in
```

or maybe

```
self.stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(self.captureConnection, completionHandler:{ (imageSampleBuffer:CMSampleBuffer!, error:NSError) -> Void in
```

then check the content of `error` before proceeding with `imageSampleBuffer`.

*Note: as I said this last part, the solution with `error`, is a guess, I didn't test: you'll have to try, adapt, and see if my idea is right or not. It would be ideal if you could find the documentation for Swift 1 about this and tell us definitely about it.*

---

Comment: Perfectly working solution. Going back, but why AVFoundation way to make a camera app is so slowly ?

Comment: Thanks. No idea, I was also a bit surprised that this problem wasn't handled more explicitly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391300/avcapture-session-slow-launch-after-session-restart  Check that solution, I've no idea how to traslate it in swift.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039799/avcapturesession-really-slowly?noredirect=1#comment55834495_34039799 @EricD.

Comment: I've seen it, don't worry. :) Unfortunately I have no answer for this other question.